# Restrict snowflake warehouse to be used by database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one snowflake instance and I want to use it for 2 different environments.

To segregate the cost, I will create 2 warehouse for dev and qa.

Also, I will create two databases. Is it possible that dev warehouse can be restricted to be used by one dev db and qa database can only be used by qa warehouse.

I know we can restrict it be roles. But it is possible on database level in snowflake?

Or if not, what is the best way - is it creating two roles and then granting the access of db and warehouse by roles?

The issue with roles is that- I can impose restrictions with application level roles but not with individual user roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to assign warehouses to databases. You need to set up (at least) 2 roles and grant required permissions to use the specific warehouse and the database.

I couldn't understand the issue with the users. You will assign these roles to users, so the users will have access to only the specific warehouse and the database.

Answer (score 2):

As Gokhan notes.

WAREHOUSES and DATABASES are just resources. They are only acted on by USER, users do stuff via ROLES.

So you have to have your QA users, have QA_x roles, and those ROLES have access to the WAREHOUSES and the DATABASES. And thus the DEV roles have access to the DEV DB & WAREHOUSE.

The only problem with this is if a USER has access to both ROLES, but then they will have to select between ROLES to access the resources, which they can use both ROLES at the same time via [USE SECONDARY ROLES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/use-secondary-roles.html) unless you have that blocked.